# opencart php / active pages

Tags: php, html, command-line, opencart

Is opencart written entirely in php or does it depend on the template?
Another problem im having is where in the server do the active pages sit? iv looked all over and only find backup pages nothing I upload changes the site.

Comment: What are you trying to do? OpenCart has a pseudo-MVC model, and stores the controllers, models, and views in appropriately named folders. You generally make changes by creating a custom template.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCart is purely PHP/MySQL. All templates will also be in PHP
All dynamic data is saved to the database itself and not in files on the server, such as products, categories, information and manufacturers - as well as all the settings you can modify

Comment: "not in files on the server" - true except for cache - which does save as files on the server by default - although I believe you can change that.

Comment: @Revent - Fair point, but they expire after an hour and updating content relevant to the cache file will delete it immediately